# Do I lose my properties in China if I give up Chinese citizenship?

Tags: legal, real-estate, chinese-citizens

I'm a Chinese citizen by birth. My parents left their property (including houses and saving accounts) to me, which are all under my name.

I'm now living in Canada and considering applying for Canadian citizenship. What happens to my property in China if I give up my Chinese citizenship?

Comment: You don't lose the properties. If the properties are of significant value, you should really consider consulting a professional who handle such cases. It will be a complex, messy, time-consuming procedure that may require your personal presence in China. There are also fiscal considerations for both sides of the Pacific.

Comment: It will be easier if the properties are in fact already under your name (i.e. all inheritance-related issues are resolved) assuming the name is identical to what will be your name on your Canadian passport. If inheritance is unresolved, it will be more difficult.

Comment: Some properties can be purchased by foreigners, some can't.  If you have the former there's obviously no problem.  Unfortunately I can't address what happens with the latter.